# How to convert karate response to String type

Tags: karate

I have a method in java that accepts String parameter. If I pass response which is karate in built variable. Java method gives exception as it is expecting double quotes in the stating.

```
* def JavaDemo = Java.type('karate.Utility.WriteJsonToFile')    
Given url 'https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123'
When method get
Then status 200  
* def sd1 = JavaDemo.writeJsonToFile(response, 'Response.json')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, please read the documentation. Here is the link to the section: [Type Conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion)

So you can do this:

```
* def JavaDemo = Java.type('karate.Utility.WriteJsonToFile')    
Given url 'https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123'
When method get
Then status 200  
* string response = response
* def sd1 = JavaDemo.writeJsonToFile(response, 'Response.json')
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed this section of documentation.